# How can I edit Azure Health Bot’s files via code?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I want to edit the Azure Health Bot’s files via code.

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming You are trying to edit the logic files in Azure Health Bot.

To edit the Azure Health Bot files, You can navigate to the `Bot Management portal`.

Now you can change the `Designer` tab to `Code` tab as below. Now you can edit the Health bot logic code.

[image]

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Could you please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.